# The value of $\sum_{r=2}^{100}\frac{3^r(2-2r)}{r(r+1)(r+2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series

$$\sum_{r=2}^{100}\dfrac{3^r(2-2r)}{r(r+1)(r+2)}$$

My attempt is as follows:-

$$-2\sum_{r=2}^{100}\dfrac{3^r(r-1)}{r(r+1)(r+2)}$$

$$-2\sum_{r=2}^{100}\dfrac{3^r}{(r+1)(r+2)}-\dfrac{3^r}{r(r+1)(r+2)}$$

$$-2\sum_{r=2}^{100}\dfrac{3^r}{(r+1)(r+2)}-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{3^r\cdot(r+2-r)}{r(r+1)(r+2)}$$

$$-2\sum_{r=2}^{100}\dfrac{3^r}{(r+1)(r+2)}-\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{3^r}{r(r+1)}-\dfrac{3^r}{(r+1)(r+2)}\right)$$

$$-2\sum_{r=2}^{100}\dfrac{3}{2}\cdot\dfrac{3^r}{(r+1)(r+2)}-\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{3^r}{r(r+1)}\right)$$

$$-\sum_{r=2}^{100}{3}\cdot\dfrac{3^r}{(r+1)(r+2)}-\left(\dfrac{3^r}{r(r+1)}\right)$$

$$-\sum_{r=2}^{100}{3}\cdot\left(\dfrac{3^r}{r+1}-\dfrac{3^r}{r+2}\right)-\left(\dfrac{3^r}{r}-\dfrac{3^r}{r+1}\right)$$

$$-\sum_{r=2}^{100}{4}\cdot\dfrac{3^r}{r+1}-3\cdot\dfrac{3^r}{r+2}-\dfrac{3^r}{r}$$

Now let's assume $S_1=\dfrac{3^r}{r+1}, S_2=\dfrac{3^r}{r+2}, S_3=\dfrac{3^r}{r}$

$$S_1=\dfrac{3^2}{3}+\dfrac{3^3}{4}+\dfrac{3^4}{5}\cdots\cdots$$

$$S_2=\dfrac{3^2}{4}+\dfrac{3^3}{5}+\dfrac{3^4}{6}\cdots\cdots$$

$$S_3=\dfrac{3^2}{2}+\dfrac{3^3}{3}+\dfrac{3^4}{4}\cdots\cdots$$

Now here I am not getting how to calculate $S_1,S_2,S_3$. Please help me in this.

Comment: $$\sum_{r=2}^{100}\left(\frac{3^{r+1}}{(r+1)(r+2)}-\frac{3^r}{r(r+1)}\right)=\frac{3^{100+1}}{(100+1)(100+2)}-\frac{3^2}{2(2+1)}$$is a telescoping series.

Comment: thanks so much, I missed that. But is there any way to calculate $S_1,S_2,S_3$

Comment: @PeterForeman But $n$ is not going to $\infty$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Oops. I was confused by the "$\dots$" at the end.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{3^n}{n+k} = \Phi(3,1,k) - 3^N \Phi(3,1,N+k) + \frac{3^N}{N+k} - \frac{1}{k}$$ where $\Phi$ is the Lerch Phi function.